# Magento: Add customer's taxvat number to billing address (address templates)

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I want to add the customer's taxvat number to the billing address.

I'd like to add it in Customer Configuration > Address Templates, so it's always visible (pdf invoice, while looking at an order in admin, etc.).

I tried quite a few variables (taxvat, customer_taxvat, customer.taxvat, etc.), but nothing seems to work. Worst part is, I don't even know where to look for the list of available variables (google doesn't give me quite what I want)

Tl;dr I want something like this:

```
{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}
{{var company}} <br /> Tax number: {{var ???}}
```

Is this easily achievable through the use of a variable or does this require a nastier solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution seems to be this:

`{{depend vat_id}}VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}`

but this might not work with OneStepCheckout extension. I haven't looked quite deep into it, but it seems OSC saves the vat_id number as some other field.